# how to change the values of inner element of Object

Tags: java, oop, object

Want to change a value of inside element of object.

[image]

Tried as below, But Unable to get a values of inner element of object. 
First for loop gives a correct output. But second for loop gives properties of object like "CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER", etc

public static void settingConcordion() throws Exception{

```
    Object Collect = config.getInstance();  
    System.out.println("*********test Please ***"+Collect);

     Class<? extends Object> c1 = Collect.getClass();

        Field[] fields = c1.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Object name = fields[i].getName();
// 1st for loop works correctly 

            if (name.equals("webConfig")){
                   System.out.println("Changes is need to  be done " + name  +"service");
               Class<? extends Object> c2 = name.getClass();
               Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                fields= c2.getDeclaredFields();
                for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++){
                    System.out.println(fields[j].getName());

//It gives me some properties values 
                }

            }
        }
```

Here is a output :- 
This is output of first for loop:-

```
INSTANCE
testTypes
keywordDrivenFilePath
kdConfig
xlsDataConfig
webConfig
```

This is output of second for loop:-

```
hash
serialVersionUID
serialPersistentFields
CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
HASHING_SEED
hash32
hash32
```

Whereas I want to fetch a value of these elements

```
currentTestBed
hub
noproxy
password
port
proxy
.
.
.
etc
```

Comment: Can you post the full output?

Comment: If I uderstand your request, your code is pretty much an overkill. You don't reflection to change values unless the field was purposely implemented as a private field without a setter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your values via calling setters using reflection like below

```
for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++){
     System.out.println(fields[j].getName());
     fields[j].setAccessible(true);
     fields[j].set(object, anyValue); // object is that object in which you want to set value
}
```

Note: setter of class attribute must be defined else it will raise exception.